# Call Main thread from secondary thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How to call Main thread from secondary thread in Android?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The simplest way is to call runOnUiThread(...) from your thread

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ... do your GUI stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'via Java'? This is Java

Comment: i mean via j2se standard java not android

Comment: For Swing see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567870/what-does-swingutilities-invokelater-do

Comment: This solution is relevant **only** for `Activity` sub-classes ([runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)))

Answer (score 24):

My recommendation to communicate threads in the same process is sending messages between those threads. It is very easy to manage this situation using Handlers:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Example of use, from Android documentation, to handling expensive work out of the ui thread:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    [ . . . ]
    // Need handler for callbacks to the UI thread
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateResultsInUi();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        [ . . . ]
    }

    protected void startLongRunningOperation() {

        // Fire off a thread to do some work that we shouldn't do directly in the UI thread
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                mResults = doSomethingExpensive();
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    private void updateResultsInUi() {

        // Back in the UI thread -- update our UI elements based on the data in mResults
        [ . . . ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a `Handler` that passes the information back to the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's good to remember that if you get your secondary thread through an AsyncTask, you have the option to call [onProgressUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29),  [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29), etc., to do work on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code using [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Handler responseHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                //txtView.setText((String) msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Result from UIHandlerThread:"+(int)msg.obj,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        };

        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("UIHandlerThread"){
            public void run(){
                /* Add your business logic to pupulate attributes in Message
                   in place of sending Integer 5 as in example code */
                Integer a = 5;
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = a;
                responseHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        };
        handlerThread.start();

    }

}
```

**Explanation:**

1. In above example, `HandlerThread` post a `Message` on `Handler` of UI Thread, which has been initialized with `Looper` of UI Thread.

   ```
   final Handler responseHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
   ```
2. `responseHandler.sendMessage(msg);` sends `Message` from `HandlerThread` to UI Thread `Handler`.
3. `handleMessage` processes `Message` received on `MessageQueue` and shows a Toast on UI Thread.