# What does SwingUtilities.invokeLater do?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

What does `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` do? Is it just delaying the execution of a block of codes inside its `run` method? What is the difference between calling an action within the `invokeLater` function or simply calling it at the end of the thread we want to be executed? Can anyone help me with what really does the `invokeLater` function do?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780936/java-eventqueue-why-should-everything-be-in-invokelater-method for background (related background, but not a duplicate).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As other answers have said, it executes your `Runnable` on the AWT event-dispatching thread.  But why would you want to do that?  Because the Swing data structures aren't thread-safe, so to provide programmers with an easily-achievable way of preventing concurrent access to them, the Swing designers laid down the rule that all code that accesses them must run on the same thread.  That happens automatically for event-handling and display maintenance code, but if you've initiated a long-running action - on a new thread, of course - how can you signal its progress or completion?  You have to modify a Swing control, and you have to do it from the event-dispatching thread.  Hence `invokeLater`.

Comment: OOH! so this is how you can do asynchronous single threading in java! It's strange that it has to be bundled with a "Windowing" toolkit though, seems a bit out of place.

Comment: @Dmitry That's a funny way to look at it. Java doesn't provide language-level support for single-threading (does any language?).  So a framework that requires it has to provide features to support it and lay down rules for the client programmer to use it correctly. This isn't "The Java way to do it", rather it's a way to do it in Java.

Answer (score 11):

It will run the piece of code on the AWT thread. Which lets you modify the GUI from other threads.

From [Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html):

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed
>   asynchronously on the AWT event
>   dispatching thread. This will happen
>   after all pending AWT events have been
>   processed. This method should be used
>   when an application thread needs to
>   update the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

As already noted, InvokeLater allows you to safely call methods in swing classes when you are not running on the EventQueue to begin with.  However, you can simplify your code and your life by accessing other fields and classes *only* from the EventQueue.  They can work with swing and each other without all the hassles of multi-threading.  If you have started another thread, use InvokeLater to get back to the EventQueue as quickly as possible and minimize the number of fields that must be synchronized or otherwise guarded.

If you need to make the most of multiple cores you will have to reduce your use of the EventQueue, and you will have to pay a big price in complexity.

Answer (score 2):

that's would be Comment, but looks like as longer as..., just basic stuff

1/ create own EDT for correct update to the GUI, f.e. if you are executed some code by using plain vanilla [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), [java.util.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) .. more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

2/ helps with set [Focus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) to the [JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) iof there are some [Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) because if is there f.e. [DocumentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) then you hard to set `Focus` to the desired `JComponents`

3/ delay code executions block and move that to the ends of EDT

Answer (score 1):

Note that you eventually get a call to your doRun.run( ) method for *every* time you call invokeLater(doRun). So if you call it ten times before the event thread gets an opportunity to perform its processing, you are likely to then get ten successive calls to doRun.run( ).