# SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

My question is related to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. When should I use it? Do I have to use each time I need to update the GUI components? What does it exactly do? Is there an alternative to it since it doesn't sound intuitive and adds seemingly unnecessary code?

Comment: It's the equivalent of `Control.BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @SLaks Does that mean if I have one thread I don't have to use it?

Comment: @FadelMS, Since the Swing frameworks spawns a thread of its own (the EDT), you'll always have that thread. (*You* don't have a "message-checking"-loop that processes user-clicks etc, right? So how does the various `actionPerformed` methods get called? By the EDT!) So when you say you have *one* thread, I would have to intepret that as you *only* have the EDT (i.e., you threw up a GUI and fell off the edge of the main method). In that case, NO, you *won't* need to use `invokeLater`. However you won't be able to do any "background" processing. If you do, you'll lock up the GUI completely...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does SwingUtilities.invokeLater do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567870/what-does-swingutilities-invokelater-do)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> ***Do I have to use each time I need to update the GUI components?***

No, not if you're already on the event dispatch thread (EDT) which is always the case when responding to user initiated events such as clicks and selections. (The `actionPerformed` methods etc, are always called by the EDT.)

If you're *not* on the EDT however and want to do GUI updates (if you want to update the GUI from some timer thread, or from some network thread etc), you'll have to *schedule* the update to be performed by the EDT. That's what this method is for.

Swing is basically thread unsafe. I.e., all interaction with that API needs to be performed on a single thread (the EDT). If you need to do GUI updates from another thread (timer thread, networking thread, ...) you need to use methods such as the one you mentioned (SwingUtilities.invokeLater, SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait, ...).

Comment: @ Jens: Which means I can do without it if I'm on the same thread (Swing) or doing things at run time.

Comment: Well, "or doing things at run time" isn't very precise. If you do things in runtime, in, say, a timer-thread, then no, you can't do without these type of methods.

Answer (score 15):

```
Swing is single threaded and all changes to the GUI must be done on EDT
```

Basic usage for `invokeLater()`

1. Main methods should be always wrapped in `invokeLater()`
2. Delayed (but asynchronously) action/event to the end of `EventQueue`,
3. If EDT doesn't exists then you have to create a new EDT by using `invokeLater()`. You can test it with  `if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {...`
4. There exists `invokeAndWait()`, but till today I (just my view) can't find a reason for using  `invokeAndWait()` instead of `invokeLater()`, except hard changes into GUI (JTree & JTable), but just with [Substance L&F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java) (excellent for testing consistency of events on the EDT)
5. Basic stuff: [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
6. All output from background tasks must be wrapped in `invokeLater()`

Answer (score 7):

Every Swing application has at least 2 threads:

1. The main thread that executes the application
2. The EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) is a thread that updates the UI (so the UI will not freeze).

If you want to update the UI you should execute code within the EDT.
Methods like SwingUtilities.invokeLater, SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait, EventQueue.invokeLater, EventQueue.invokeAndWait allow you to execute code by the EDT.

Answer (score 7):

> My question this time is related to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`: When should I use it?

What is key to understand is that Java has a separate thread (EDT) handling Swing related events.

You should use `invokeLater()` to display the main `JFrame` of a desktop application (for example), instead of trying to do it in the current thread. It will also create the context for graceful closing of the application later.

That's about it for most applications.

> Do I have to use each time I need to update the GUI components? What does it exactly do?

No. If you modify a GUI component, it will trigger an event which is registered for later dispatching by Swing. If there is a listener for this event, the EDT thread will call it somewhere down the road. You don't need to use `invokeLater()`, just set your listeners on components properly.

Keep in mind that this thread is the same thread drawing frames etc... on your screen. Hence, listeners should not perform complex/long/CPU intensive tasks, otherwise your screen will freeze.

> Is there an alternative to it since it doesn't sound intuitive and adds seemingly unnecessary code?

You don't need to write more code than displaying your application with `invokeLater()` + listeners you are interested in on component. The rest is handled by Swing.

Answer (score 3):

Most user-initiated events (clicks, keyboard) will already be on the EDT so you won't have to use SwingUtilities for that.  That covers a lot of cases, except for your main() thread and worker threads that update the EDT.

Comment: Well, a user could update a file that is being monitored by a thread that updates the GUI.

Comment: hmm ... that doesn't count as a (direct, that's where the rule holds) user-initiated event: the user updates the file (inside swing, on EDT) and save it (via clicking a button, on EDT), which triggers an OS file-update event (outside swing, off EDT) notification, that notification reaches the monitor (off EDT) which is responsible for updating the GUI on EDT