# How to make a thread not freeze you whole JFrame. JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jframe, freeze

Hey i just need a question answered...
How would i make the following code not freeze my whole JFrame?

```
                try {
                Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(delayField.getText()) * 1000);
                System.out.println("Hello!");
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use a different thread to perform this task. If you do this in the main UI thread then it will freeze.. For example you can do following

```
  new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(delayField.getText()) * 1000);
                System.out.println("Hello!");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

        }
    }.start();
```

**UPDATE**

AFter wise suggestions of Robin and Marko I am updating the answer with a better solution.

```
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Hello!");

        }
    };
    javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(Integer.parseInt(delayField.getText()) * 1000, taskPerformer);
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();
```

Comment: Since `JTextField#getText` is not thread-safe, you shouldn't be calling that method from another thread then the EDT

Comment: @Robin, yup didn't think about that while postin :(... a synchronized method can be used to get the text.. will there be any side affect of that?

Comment: I would retrieve the text outside of that thread, and simply pass it in there. And simply for delay, I would ditch the thread completely and use a Timer as suggested by Marko Topolnik

Comment: Thanks @Robin for enlighting me .. I am updating the answer accorind to your advice

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are about to use `Thread.sleep` in your GUI code, stop yourself and think of Swing Timer, which is the right tool for the job. Schedule the task you need to perform with a delay.

Using another thread for this is not the best advice: it wastes a heavy system resource (a thread) to do absolutely nothing but wait.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct way to use threads in java . You should use swingutilities.invokelater

[swing utils invoke later](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to execute this on the UI (or *event dispatch thread*) thread. Rather in a separate thread. Otherwise (as you've seen) you'll block the UI.

It's a good practice to perform time-consuming operations on a separate thread, and make use of [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater) if those threads need to perform some subsequent UI action (e.g. in the above display "Hello" in the UI)