# JFrame not sizing correctly

Tags: java, jframe, size, contentpane, insets

When I set the size of the JFrame its set the size of the frame itself including the borders.
I tried creating a new content Panel and set that size instead of setting the size of the frame itself but it isn't working here is the code:

```
frame = new JFrame();
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
frame.setTitle(title);
//frame.setSize(width, height);
frame.setResizable(false); 
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//insets = frame.getInsets();
//frame.setSize(new Dimension(insets.left + width + insets.right, insets.top + height + insets.bottom));
jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
frame.setContentPane(jp);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

So using insets isn't working and using a new ContentPane is also not working I hope it is clear enough.

**EDIT:** It's working now I extended the class with Canvas set it's size to width and height and then added it to the JFrame then packed it. This works! But why I think caused it was not the sizing but the way I rendered it, I got the bufferStrategy from the JFrame instead of the canvas which is not the way it should be.

Comment: I just tried and `setPreferredSize` on the `ContentPane` is definitely working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `getPreferredSize()` to set the preferred size of the `JPanel`.

Sample code:

```
JPanel panel =new JPanel (){

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
}
```

See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

---

Use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)  to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

sample code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // GUI related code goes here (not heavy task)
        }
    });
}
```

See [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)

---

Why are you setting new content pane of `JFrame`? Just add in the default content pane using `frame.getContentPane().add(panel)` or `frame.add(panel)`

Call `frame.setResizable(false)` in the end after making it visible to make sure that all the components are fit properly.