# Synchronized methods vs SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-synchronization

In my project I have a class extending a JFrame. It exposes some methods wich are used by many threads.
I am wondering what is the best approach between these two in order to avoid concurrency issues:

```
public synchronized void doStuff1(final String arg) {
        /*
         * do stuff synchronized...
         */
    }

    public synchronized void doStuff2(final String arg) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /*
                 * do stuff invoke later...
                 */
            }
        });
    }
```

Wich one is the most performing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater?rq=1

Comment: It's not a matter of performance.  If your doStuff method is in a different thread than the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), Oracle and I **require** that you use the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.