# How do I box/cast Java classes to parent class types?

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to write a screen manager in Java - a language I am new to. This class (ScreenManager) should be able to take a class type and then instantiate it. It's easier to explain with code so, I want to be able to do this:

```
ScreenManager manager = new ScreenManager();
manager.setCurrentScreen(MenuScreen.class);
manager.runScreen();
```

MenuScreen extends a class called Screen which extends JFrame. My idea is to have AScreen, BScreen, CScreen etc all extend Screen so I can cast them to Screen and store them as one single type.

So ScreenManager is like this:

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class ScreenManager {

    private Class<Screen> _currentScreen;
    private Screen _currentScreenObject;

    public ScreenManager() { }

    public ScreenManager(Class<Screen> screen) {
        setCurrentScreen(screen);       
    }

    public Class<Screen> getCurrentScreen() {
        return _currentScreen;          
    }

    public void setCurrentScreen(Class<Screen> screen) {
        _currentScreen = screen;
    }

    public void runScreen() {
        if (_currentScreen == null) return;
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);                
                try {
                    _currentScreenObject = _currentScreen.newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Screen is simply, and all AScreen, BScreen etc have is some initialisation code in their constructors.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

---

The bit I am stumbling on is passing the class type to the ScreenManager class.

```
ScreenManager manager = new ScreenManager();
manager.setCurrentScreen(MenuScreen.class);
manager.runScreen();
```

Now I can cast it like so:

```
Screen s = new MenuScreen();
```

But I can't seem to pass the class type. I've tried to cast it like so:

```
manager.setCurrentScreen((Screen.class)MenuScreen.class);
```

That doesn't work.

FYI, I come from a C# background, so my perspective may (and probably is) wrong. If so, please correct me.

Thanks for reading this far!

Comment: Why not just manager.setCurrentScreen(new MenuScreen())?

Comment: Yeah, that part is confusing me, too.  It's rare in Java in a relatively simple application to be fussing with the actual class as opposed to instances of that class.

Comment: I was under the impression I needed to run in with `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567870/what-does-swingutilities-invokelater-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Class<? extends Screen>` instead of `Class<Screen>`. It will then accept both `Screen.class` and `MenuScreen.class`, given `MenuScreen` extends `Screen`. Sort of Java's equivalence to C#'s generics covariance...

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! I actually saw this in some documentation I read but didn't notice it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C#, type parameters in Java are a compile-time-only feature and are not covariant.

In Java a `List<Integer>` is not a `List<Number>`.

You can specify "some unknown subtype of Screen" by declaring it as `Class<? extends Screen>`.  That's the best Java can do, because it is only checking the types when it runs the compiler, not when you run the code like C# does.

Comment: Ah I see. Makes sense now. Class<? extends Screen> works. Thanks! +1