# How to use JScrollPane alongside JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have written this code. Here I want to make a JScrollPane work with JTextArea. But it is not working at all. Earlier I almost did the same thing. It used to work. Please provide a solution. Thanks in advance. I have posted the code.

```
    protected void startServerProcess(int port) {
    serverFrame = new JFrame("SERVER NOTIFICATIONS PANEL | Labyrinth Developers");
    serverFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    serverFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    serverFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    serverFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    serverFrame.setVisible(true);

    notificationsTA = new JTextArea();
    notificationsTA.setBounds(0,0,466,500);
    notificationsTA.setLineWrap(true);
    notificationsTA.setRows(1000);

    notificationsSP = new JScrollPane();
    notificationsSP.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    notificationsSP.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    notificationsSP.setViewportView(notificationsTA);
    notificationsSP.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
    notificationsSP.setBounds(470, 0, 30, 500);

    serverFrame.add(notificationsTA);
    serverFrame.add(notificationsSP);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JTextArea` is already added in `JScrollPane` so there is no need to add it again in `JFrame` as well. Remove below line:

```
serverFrame.add(notificationsTA);
```

You can add the component in the viewport of scroll pane using its [Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane%28java.awt.Component%29) as well that internally calls [JScrollPane#setViewport()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewport%28javax.swing.JViewport%29) method.

```
notificationsSP = new JScrollPane(notificationsTA);
```

---

#### Some Points:

- [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) be default uses [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) and you can add only single component in each section (North, South, East, West and Center).

  Read more [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
- Call `serverFrame.setVisible(true);` in the end after adding all the components.
- Don't use `setBounds()` at all. Just leave it for *Layout Manager* to set the size and position of the components.
- Use  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

  Read more

  - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
  - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)

Comment: Thanks...you are right...I forgot that constructor for JScrollPane...My bad I should have used Javadocs....And regarding setVisible...yeah we should use at last to avoid flickers and actually I have used invokeLater but this was an excerpt of the code. Thanks once again to remind me..:)