# Close the current window and open the previous window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am a beginner to java and stuck with the below issue.
The purpose is to display the login window when log out button is pressed.

First JFrame window displayed is "Plain" with 2 fields username and password(I will be adding the log in functionality later)

When I press the submit button the JFrame "NEw Window" is displayed with the button "LOGOUT"

What I would like to do is that when the "LOGOUT" is pressed the "NEw Window" should close and the "Plain" window should open.

Present issue: When "LOGOUT" button is pressed the "NEw Window" is opening up.

Please correct the code so that I get the desired functionality

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

class Test implements ActionListener{
    JButton submit;
    JFrame j;
    JFrame jf;

    public Test()
    {
    j = new JFrame("PLAIN");
    j.setBounds(500,150,300,400);
    j.setVisible(true);
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(j.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    j.add(panel);
    panel.setSize(50, 50);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("User Name");
    label.setSize(10,10);
    label.setBounds(100, 30, 400, 30);
    panel.add(label);

    JTextField username = new JTextField(10);
    username.setSize(10,10);
    username.setBounds(300, 30, 400, 30);
    panel.add(username);

    JLabel password= new JLabel("Password");
    password.setBounds(100, 90, 400, 30);
    panel.add(password);

    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
    pass.setBounds(300, 90, 400, 30);
    panel.add(pass);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.setSize(10, 10);
    submit.setBounds(300, 160, 200, 40);
    panel.add(submit);

    submit.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        j.setVisible(false);
        jf = new JFrame("NEw Window");
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setBounds(500,150,300,400);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(null);
        jf.add(panel2);

        JButton logout = new JButton("LOGOUT");
        logout.setBounds(100, 30, 400, 30);
        panel2.add(logout);
        logout.addActionListener(this);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(j.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e1) {

        jf.dispose();
        j.setVisible(true);


    }

public static void main(String args[])
{

    new Test();

}

}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead [use layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Some Points:

1. Call `JFrame#setVisible()` in the end after adding all the components.
2. Never use `null` layout at all instead use proper Layout Manager.

   Read more [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) where all the layout manger are described in detail along with sample code.
3. Use  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

   Read more

   - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
   - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)

Try with [WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) instead of [JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE).

Answer (score 0):

Just put j.setVisible(true) from Test() at the end, after adding all the components.

If you want to make a new form, don't do it in the same class where you already have one because it isn`t right.
Read the book named Clean code. You also have some errors in your code and useless.

Comment: As I told above that i am beginner to Java and not an expert. So please don't call my code as useless. Remember The Expert in anything was once a beginner.

Comment: Hei, I`m sorry if I offended you, that was not the idea. I said that you wrote some useless code, it`s just an observation. You have to learn from this kind of observations. Obviously, nobody is an expert in the  beginning.