# Adding Jtable into jframe

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to add a JTable into the frame, but no works, i had tried:

```
public Jtablee()
    {
        setSize(400,400);

        String[] columnsNames = {"firstName", "LastName", "sport", "# ofYear", "vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {{"Katty", "Smith", "SnowBoard", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)}, {"Jhon", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},{"Jane", "White", "Speed ride", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)}};

        JTable t = new JTable(data, columnsNames);
        add(t.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Just the blank frame appear, without the JTable

Note: I don't want to add it into a scrollPane, I wanna add it directly.

Comment: What happens when you do this? Is the frame displayed at all? Any exception?

Comment: @Thomas A blank jframe appear without the JTABLE

Comment: You might want to provide more information in that case, i.e. when do you add the table? What data/columns do you initialize it with? How's your frame configured? etc.

Comment: 1) Add your JTable to a JScrollPane's viewport and add the scrollpane to the JFrame's contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER. 2) If this doesn't work, then you must show more pertinent code, preferably a [mcve]. Please read the link.

Comment: Don't call `setLayout(...)`. The JFrame's contentPane already uses a BorderLayout.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels even if a set a null frame Layout the error persist

Comment: @Cohen: using a null layout is the worst thing you can do to try to solve this. The best thing (again), is to post a complete compilable runnable **small** example program, a [mcve] that we can test ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing you have to do to let visible your JTable, is delete the `"setLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER)",` cause that's making conflict with your code (it's overrading the BorderLayout previously create).

Comment: Once you start adding panels, please do not change the layout, even for the same layout.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call `setLayout(new BorderLayout())` as the content pane `Container` already has that layout. Calling it **after** adding your components will make them vanish.

You also do not need to call `setSize()` on the `JFrame`. Instead you should call `pack()` which will automatically resize it to fit its contents (the table)

Finally you should not be be using `new Integer()` and `new Boolean()` here as it is unnecessary boxing, instead use the primitives.

So your code should look like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {

        String[] columnsNames = {"firstName", "LastName", "sport", "# ofYear", "vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
                {"Katty", "Smith", "SnowBoard", 5, false},
                {"Jhon", "Doe", "Rowing", 3, true},
                {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", 2, false},
                {"Jane", "White", "Speed ride", 20, true}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnsNames);
        add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to wrap [calls to Swing components on the EDT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)

Answer (score 0):

I want here to present my example to add a simple table into JFrame using JScrollPane and without possibility of reordering the table header by users.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class addTable extends JFrame{

    JTable table;
    public addTable(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        String [] columnNames = {
            "First name", "Last name", "Header"};
        Object [][] data = {{ "Bill", "George", "Male"}, 
            {"Marry", "Anna", "Female"}, {"Rick",  
            "Bernard", "Male"}};
        table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(650, 75) );
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        addTable t = new addTable();
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(800, 400);
        t.setTitle("My Table");
        t.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```