# JTable validate cell value by user input based on another column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hello I have a simple JTable, there are six columns that matter have header described in Table Model:

```
private final String[] columNames = new String[]{"Id","TicketID","PolicyNo","Remarks 1","Hourly Rate","Part Time","Validate 1"};
```

I need to validate each time user enters 3 digits that must be equal based on last 3 digits value from Column (2). Please see the picture below
[image: Run File]

this is my code

```
private final DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new TabelaCellRenderer();

/**
 * Creates new form EditableTableExample
 */
public EditableTableExample() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Editable Table Example");
    initTable();
}

private void initTable(){
    DocsDetail row1 = new DocsDetail(1, "1216266","19889086","", 100.0, true,0);
    DocsDetail row2 = new DocsDetail(1, "1216266","33350761","", 100.0, false,0);
    DocsDetail row3 = new DocsDetail(1, "1216266","22780770","", 100.0, true,0);
    DocsDetail row4 = new DocsDetail(1, "1216266","57611607","", 100.0, false,0);
    DocsDetail row5 = new DocsDetail(1, "1216266","72914755","", 100.0, true,0);

    //build the list
    List<DocsDetail> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    employeeList.add(row1);
    employeeList.add(row2);
    employeeList.add(row3);
    employeeList.add(row4);
    employeeList.add(row5);

    //create the model
    DocsDetailTabelModel model = new DocsDetailTabelModel(employeeList);
    //create the table
    tableEx.setModel(model);
    tableEx.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(model));
    //tableEx.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
    //tableEx.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellEditor(new IntegerEditor(0, 1000));
}

private class TabelaCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jtable, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        String nopolis = "";
        int lastDigits = 0;
        int modelRow = jtable.convertRowIndexToView(row);
        jtable.convertRowIndexToView(row);
        nopolis = jtable.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 2).toString();
        lastDigits = Integer.parseInt(nopolis.substring(nopolis.length() - 3));
        if (column == 6) {
            if(!value.equals(0)){
                System.out.println("lastDigits: "+lastDigits);
                if (value.equals(lastDigits)) {
                   jtable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
                    setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                } else {
                   jtable.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
                   setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                }
            }
        }else {
            setForeground(Color.black);
            setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Looks pretty simple(or not simple hehe). Except that I have no idea what event should I look for. Something like "cell value changed"? or Cell Validator or Cell Renderer, i already try those methods but i did not find solution for my case ;( Anyway, before I come up with some weird noobish solution I thought I might ask here what's the proper way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom editor to edit the data as it is being entered.

Check out the [Table Five Character Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390445/swing-catching-exceptions-from-tablemodel/20390486#20390486) for an example to get you started.

The example there just makes sure you enter 5 characters in the cell. You would obviously change the edit to validate the 3 characters entered.