# How to read File and write content into JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to transfer content from a text file into a `JTextarea`. I suppose my code just needs small adjustments but even through research. I am not able to find out, what is wrong. So far it is just displaying an empty `JFrame` instead of the text of the file.

```
this.setSize(this.width, this.height);
this.setVisible(true);
this.jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.jTextArea);
this.jPanel = new JPanel();
this.jPanel.setOpaque(true);
this.jTextArea.setVisible(true);

try {
    this.jTextArea = new JTextArea();
    this.jTextArea.read(new InputStreamReader(
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\wrk\\SapCommerceCloud\\src\\SwingUni\\name")),
        null);

} // catch

    this.add(this.jScrollPane);
```

And the usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TextFrame(new File("C:\\wrk\\SapCommerceCloud\\src\\SwingUni\\name"), 500, 500);
}
```

Comment: `''CATCHING EXCEPTIONS HERE''` What does that mean? What does the code do once it's caught one? 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 3) [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,java.lang.Object)) provides an easy way 2 load text into a Swing text component.

Comment: You're adding your text area to a JScrollPane, then make it visible, then create a new, different JTextArea, which is never added to any container, but which is filled with the content of a classpath resource. Don't create two text areas. And read the documentation of getResourceAsStream() to understand what kind of path it expects: it's not an absolute file path.

Comment: Here is a complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691384/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 important issues in this code:

- You are creating jScrollPane `this.jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.jTextArea);` before reading the file content using `jTextArea`
- The method does not work `read(new InputStreamReader(
  getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\wrk\\SapCommerceCloud\\src\\SwingUni\\name")), null);` Use the one in the following example.

You have to catch the exception to solve the problems

```
  public class TextAreaDemo extends JFrame {

    private JScrollPane jScrollPane;
    private JTextArea jTextArea ;
    private static final String FILE_PATH="/Users/user/IdeaProjects/StackOverflowIssues/file.txt";

 public TextAreaDemo() {

        try {
            jTextArea = new JTextArea(24, 31);

            jTextArea.read(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH)), null);

        } catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.jTextArea);
        this.add(this.jScrollPane);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(400, 200);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextAreaDemo textAreaDemo = new TextAreaDemo();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I could fix it.