# Use parameters passed into event listener by background thread on Main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have a class of this form.

```
class TestClass implements SomeInterface {

    Data myData;

    public TestClass() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onData(Data data) {
        // do stuff with data
        myData = data
    }
}
```

where `SomeInterface` does some data processing on a background thread and calls `onData`, which runs on a background thread as well. I want to be able to use the data returned in `onData` on the `Main` thread (updating UI, do other stuff on main thread, etc.) because I know exactly how long after I call the background thread, `onData` will be called. Since I'm using `SomeInterface` from some library, I can't modify this functionality (I'm not exactly using it as intended).

In Android I would have done something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388415/call-main-thread-from-secondary-thread-in-android) but I obviously can't do it in a pure Java application since there's no such thing as a `Looper`. Setting an instance variable from a background thread doesn't let me access it from the main thread as well.

Comment: If you use AWT or swing, then use [`EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Have a look at `SwingWorker` which is basically the same thing for Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html  Note that on neither Android nor Java desktop does the main thread update the gui.

Comment: What GUI framework?  Swing, for example, provides `SwingWorker` and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` which provide you means to move execution onto the main thread

Comment: I’m not using Swing, AWT, or any UI library. I just used updating the UI as an example.

Comment: If it's not Swing or AWT, what UI is it?

Comment: I’m not using any UI. I just used UI as an example of what can be accomplished. Is there no way to do this independently of a UI framework?

Comment: Ah, have a look at `ExecutorService` then, look at thread pools, and the `Callable` interface.

Comment: GUI frameworks use a producer/consumer pattern.  Basically thread x places a "object" of specific type onto the GUI's event queue.  The main (or event dispatching) thread will process this queue.  When it finds an instance of the "specific type of object" it will perform the required operation on it, which means that operation is executed within the context of the main thread - In Swing/AWT, this "specific" object is an instance of `Runnable` and the EDT executes the `run` method on it.  You could devise something simular

Comment: @MadProgrammer how does thread x update a variable (event queue) on the Main thread? This is essentially the same functionality I want. Instead of adding to a queue I simply want to set an instance variable

Comment: @Carpetfizz As I said, you can use a producer/consumer pattern.  The idea is. You have the "main" thread, which would be reading from the "queue" and processing it's content.  You would have `onData` wrap `data` in the "queue"s expected type and push it onto the queue.  The "main" thread would then pop it off the queue and execute it's functionality.  In the case of Swing and Android, they use `Runnable`s, where the "main" thread would just call the `run` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, I agree with you on the pattern. However I was asking how onData would write data into a queue that the Main thread can read from. In my example above onData is setting an instance variable but the Main thread was unable to read this instance variable. If onData writes into a queue which is an instance variable, how can the Main thread read from it?

Comment: @Carpetfizz Technically, you could use a `BlockingQueue` of some kind

Comment: cant you use volatile on the variable ??

Answer (score 0):

You could invent your own framework, but that would be kind of silly.  `ExecutorService` and other classes from `java.util.concurrent` basically do this all for you with only a little bit of assembly.

Here I create some input data on the main thread, pass it to a background thread by using the `Callable` interface and an executor.  Then the main thread gets the output data from the background thread using a `Future` object.  Easy peasy.

```
public abstract class SimpleBackgroundService {

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

      final InputData input = new InputData( 123, "Hi Mom" ); // really should be immutable

      Callable<OutputData> task = new Callable<OutputData>() {
         private final InputData taskInput = input;
         @Override
         public OutputData call() {
            return new OutputData( taskInput );
         }
      };

      ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 );
      Future<OutputData> taskOutput = es.submit( task );
      // do some stuff here while the task completes.
      OutputData data = taskOutput.get();  // will block and wait if needed
      System.out.println( data );
   }

   static class InputData {

      private final int num;
      private final String msg;

      public InputData( int num, String msg ) {
         this.num = num;
         this.msg = msg;
      }

   }
   static class OutputData {

      private final int num2;
      private final String msg2;

      public OutputData( InputData dat ) {
         num2 = dat.num;
         msg2 = dat.msg;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I unfortunately don’t have the luxury of calling the task itself. I just subscribe to an event listener from some jar which calls the handler on my class

Comment: You should have mentioned that from the start.  You really aren't making it easy to answer the question, are you?  Put the full information in the OP and maybe someone will answer it.

Comment: I believe I said in the OP I can’t modify the functionality of the library